# How can I check on already created entries in my model?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am quite new to sapui5 and can't solve the following problem.

I have a SplitApp.
When I chose the first entry in my master view, a detail view is called. In the onInit event from the detail view the method createEntry runs. To process my input data I call submitChanges.

Now when I call the second entry on my master view, another view is called and for that second view the onInit event runs and creates an own entry. But the created entry from the first view  from the method createEntry will not be deleted. 
Now I call the first entry on my master view and again the onInit event runs and a second ID for that first view will be created. This leads to a mistake when I run the submitChanges method.
The more often I switch between the views, the more entries I create.

So is there an event I can use to call deleteCreatedEntry? I already tried onExit and onBeforeHide.
Or is it better to check, if an entry is already created? Which code do I have to use for this?

```
this.oContext = this.getModel().createEntry("/MyoData01Set", {
                success: this._successSave.bind(this),
                error: this._errorSave.bind(this)
            });
```

Many thanks and best regards
Julia

In addition 13.05.20:

I implemented the suggestion, but still it is not working. I get an error, when I try to enter the method _this.*bindNewContext();*
Please take a look at the code:

```
handleMatchedDetail: function (oEvent) {
            this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then(function () {
                this.getModel().resetChanges().then(function () {
                    this._bindNewContext();
                });
            }.bind(this));
        },

        _bindNewContext: function () {
            this.oContext = this.getModel().createEntry("/Kardex01Set", {
                success: this._successSave.bind(this),
                error: this._errorSave.bind(this)
            });
            // }
            var oBindingPath = {
                path: this.oContext.getPath(),
                events: {
                    change: function () {
                        this.getModel().read("/Kardex01Set('0')", {
                            success: function (oData, oResponse) {
                                this.getView().getModel().setProperty(this.oContext.getPath() + "/tanum", oData.tanum);
                            }.bind(this)
                        });
                    }.bind(this)
                }
            };
            this.getView().bindObject(oBindingPath);
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply call `resetChanges` on your model. This will delete all changes that have not been submitted yet.

See the [API description](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel%23methods/resetChanges) for details.

Comment: Many thanks. I really appreciate your answer. But when I call it before the createEntry method, nothing changes. I suppose I called the resetChanges method in a wrong way.

```
this.getModel().resetChanges();
   this.oContext = this.getModel().createEntry("/MyoData01Set", {
    success: this._successSave.bind(this),
    error: this._errorSave.bind(this)
   });
```
The debugger still shows me all created entries:

this.getModel().oData;
MyoData01Set('id-1587111506114-11'): {…}
MyoData01Set('060'): {__metadata: {…},  …}
MyoData02Set('id-1587111533879-18'): {...}
BR, Julia

Comment: `resetChanges()` is asynchronous, it returns a Promise. You should wait for the Promise to resolve, like so: `this.getModel().resetChanges().then(function() {/*remaining code here*/});`

Comment: Hi, many thanks, but it doesn't work in my coding. There must be some mistake left. In lack of an event to call the method, I called it before creating the new entry. Sorry for being such a noob :( I made the following for testing it:

```handleMatchedDetail: function (oEvent) {
   this.getModel().metadataLoaded().then(function () {
    this._resetChanges();
    this._bindNewContext();
   }.bind(this));
```
and:
```
_resetChanges: function () {
   this.getModel().resetChanges().then(function() { 
    sap.m.MessageToast.show("resetChanges");
   });
  },
```
Best regards
Julia

Comment: You can call `this.getModel().getPendingChanges()` to see the unsubmitted changes. Call it before and after calling `resetChanges` to see what happens.

Comment: Many thanks for your answers. I really appreciate the effort you make :)
Using getPendingChanges() I see, that the pending Changes will be deleted when I call resetChanges(). But I guess, this is not what I need. Maybe there is an misunderstanding.

Comment: So I tried deleteCreatedEntry() That works fine when called. But my problem is:
I call the first item from my Masterview. This creates an entry (createEntry()).
I call the second item from my Masterview. The first entry is not deleted (because I find no event, that runs). The second item creates an entry as well.
I call the first item again. This creates a second entry for the first one. With those 3 entries a have trouble when I call "submitChanges".

Comment: Many thanks @Marc and @Johann! I had some issues to implement that method correctly, but now it seems to work! How can I reward your answers in here?
Best regards